# Custom layout weird bug

Tags: android

I'm facing a weird bug , if i remove the first layout(id = firstLayout) the second layout(id = user_home_buttonsLLay) works fine with their borders , but when i put all together the buttons border disappear  . The most strange is that it was working fine before . Thanks for any help.

My Layout :

```
<LinearLayout id="@+id/firtLayout" style="@style/headerLLay">

    <ImageView style="@style/header_left_img" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/user_home_headerTitulo"
        android:text="Usuário" style="@style/header_titulo" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/user_home_headerImgBtInfo"
        style="@style/header_right_img" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/user_home_buttonsLLay"
    style="@style/user_home_buttonsLLay">

    <Button android:id="@+id/user_home_bt_novoCliente" style="@style/user_home_button"
        android:text="@string/user_home_novoCliente" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/user_home_bt_jaCadastrado" style="@style/user_home_button"
        android:text="@string/user_home_jaCadastrado" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Buttons Style

```
<style name="user_home_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">200dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">40dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bt_padrao_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dip</item>
</style>
```

---

Buttons selector

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item      
    android:drawable="@drawable/bt_padrao" />
 <item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/bt_padrao_pressed" />

      </selector>
```

---

Buttons custom background with borders

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:left="1dp"
            android:top="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:bottom="1dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:left="2dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:bottom="2dp"/>
        <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="90"/>
        <corners android:radius="1dp"/>    
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already find the answer , somehow the background of my imagebutton which was set to (#00000000) to make it transparent, was interfering on the other components . Like float in css without clear after may disturb the rest of the page. I solve it using image instead of imagebutton , which lets me remove the background (#00000000)  .